# Application freezes when creating datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am using the following code to read an Excel file into a datagridview (EquipmentDataGrid).  The first time it builds the datagridview it works perfectly, however, if I navigate back to the tab page (and thus re run the code) it freezes and takes about 10 minutes for the UI to become responsive. I can't figure out what the issue is since it always works fine on the first go. I am VERY new to programming (just started about 1 week ago from no prior experience) so sorry if this is a simple fix.

```
Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged

    If TabControl1.SelectedTab Is Equipment Then
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xLBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xLSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim x As Integer

        EquipmentDataGrid.Rows.Clear()
        EquipmentDataGrid.Columns.Clear()

        xlApp = New Excel.Application


        xLBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(My.Settings.SharefilePath + "Equipment Moves\EquipmentLog")
        xLSheet = xLBook.Worksheets("Summary")

        EquipmentDataGrid.ColumnCount = 5
        EquipmentDataGrid.Columns(0).Name = "Date"
        EquipmentDataGrid.Columns(1).Name = "Equipment Number"
        EquipmentDataGrid.Columns(2).Name = "Description"
        EquipmentDataGrid.Columns(3).Name = "Hours"
        EquipmentDataGrid.Columns(4).Name = "Location"


        For x = 1 To xLSheet.Range("F1").Value
            EquipmentDataGrid.Rows.Add()
            EquipmentDataGrid.Item(0, x - 1).Value = xLSheet.Cells(1 + x, 1).Text
            EquipmentDataGrid.Item(1, x - 1).Value = xLSheet.Cells(1 + x, 2).value
            EquipmentDataGrid.Item(2, x - 1).Value = xLSheet.Cells(1 + x, 5).value
            EquipmentDataGrid.Item(3, x - 1).Value = xLSheet.Cells(1 + x, 3).value
            EquipmentDataGrid.Item(4, x - 1).Value = xLSheet.Cells(1 + x, 4).value
        Next
        xLBook.Saved = True
        xLBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp)
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xLBook)
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xLSheet)

        x = Nothing
        xLBook = Nothing
        xLSheet = Nothing
        xlApp = Nothing

        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        GC.Collect()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Because you are in VB, I am assuming you are in Visual Studio.  Try adding a breakpoint to your code.  This will allow you to stop your code on the breakpoint and look at the values.  This is a debugging processes and may lend you an error or more information.  Here is a link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pranayamr/setting-breakpoints-in-visual-studio/

Comment: I have one suggestion to you, that will make your program brilliant. Use `microsoft.ace.oledb.xxx` provider to connect to your `excel` sheet like you would connect to DB. Read the data into a `list (of excelModel)` where excel model is nothing more than a POCO class, that can hold your worksheet data. Then bind your grid to this list using `datasource, displaymember, valuememeber`. You will be in good shape. Or, you can load a `dataset` and bind that. Loading into model will give you more flexibility. And the best of it, you can edit this stuff right in grid and save it back to excel. wow

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is only on runs after the first run, my guess would be that the clearing of the grid is the issue. Like JabberWocky suggests, stick a breakpoint before the lines clearing the grid and one after so you can get a sense of how long that step takes.

If that is the issue there doesn't seem to be much of a way around the issue. You could wrap the clearing lines in some logic so that they aren't run if the data in the Excel file matches what's in your grid, but that won't help if there is new/changed data to load.